# Rename [itertools]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I recently clicked on a question tagged with [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools), thinking it was a Python question. It turned out it was a Rust question, as there is also a Rust crate named "itertools".

I edited the tag info to indicate that it could refer to both a Python module and a Rust crate, but I don't know if that's the best approach. (It's the *simplest* approach for now.)

A new tag [rust-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-itertools) could be created for the crate, and the original [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) could either be left as-is or renamed to [python-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-itertools).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Where possible, tags shouldn't refer to multiple things. So, having [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) be for both Python's [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and Rust's [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/) at the same time isn't a good idea. There are currently [only 15 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bitertools%5D+%5Brust%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) which have both [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) and [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust).

*snip: it looks like [E_net4 the comment flagger's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421588/3773011) covers everything I was going to say about the starting situation*

Actions done:

- Edited all [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) questions to include [rust-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-itertools) (1 question)
  Looking at [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44139493), it's asking about how to do something in Rust's itertools based on how they did something in in Python's itertools, so ending up with both [rust-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-itertools) and [python-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-itertools) doesn't appear unreasonable. Subject mater experts are welcome to edit this if they want something different.
- Edited all [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) questions to replace [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) with [rust-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-itertools) (14 questions)
- Search for all [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) questions which don't contain [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) and which contain "itertools::" (none, after above changes)
- Search for all [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) questions which don't contain [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) and which match the regular expression `/^use itertools/m` (none, after above changes)
- Search for all [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) questions which don't contain [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) and which match the regular expression `/\brust\b/i` (none, after above changes)
- Renamed [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) to [python-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-itertools) (1 tag changed: affected 2,939 questions).
- Go to edit the tag wiki excerpts and histories for [python-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-itertools) and [rust-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-itertools). See that they have already been edited by [E_net4 the comment flagger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233251/e-net4-the-comment-flagger). Yay! Less work. :) Thanks.
- Create [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) ➞ [python-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-itertools) synonym.

Answer (score 6):

Despite the similarities, it would be incorrect to assume that followers of an `itertools` tag would be interested in following all of the Python package, the Rust crate, not to mention whichever library comes around for a different technology. Not to mention that a subject matter expert of one kind of itertools will *definitely* not make that user an expert in the other.
While it is true that the `itertools` Rust crate emerged many years later, possibly inspired by `itertools` Python package, they differ enough to be tracked independently in the site's tag system.

Merging both libraries here was a mistake. I have already proposed to resolve this with a tag edit.
With that said, at the time of writing there are:

- 2,954 questions in total tagged [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools)
- 15 questions tagged both [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) and [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust).
- 210 questions tagged [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) with neither [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) nor [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust), but they are mostly Python questions which do not have the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag.
- only 1 question happens to have the three ([itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust)), where the asker probably means the Python package and one of the answers happens to use the `itertools` crate.

Moving forward, I believe that the best course of action is edit all Rust questions to remove [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) and possibly add a [rust-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-itertools) tag. We should also turn [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itertools) into a synonym of [python-itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-itertools), thus helping break this ambiguity.