# The tag [chrono] is used for both C++ and Rust

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

Both [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) and [Rust](http://docs.rs/chrono) have libraries named `chrono`. Currently, most questions in the [chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono) tag are about C++ (837 questions) and the tag description is also explicitly about it, but there are 19 questions tagged [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) [chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono).

It may be good to have separate [chrono-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono-c%2b%2b) and [chrono-rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono-rust) tags, or at least have a [chrono-rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono-rust) tag and referring to it in the [chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono) tag.

Comment: Does `chrono` in Rust do something different to the `chrono` in C++, or do they actually achieve the same thing(s)?

Comment: @Larnu Both are date&time libraries. But I think the policy is still to have them separate, no?

Comment: If you retag the rust questions to [rust-chrono] (the normal convention is lang-thing rather than thing-lang), I can rename the existing tag afterwards. The libraries are different, so they shouldn't have a unified tag

Comment: The numbers don't add up! (938 total questions.) Some of that's because people are using version tags (eg c++11) and some of that's because there are questions that are not about C++ or Rust. Someone needs to go through those questions before a massive rename.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: Most C++-specific tags put the C++ first. Like "c++-modules" and "c++-coroutines".

Comment: @NicolBolas yeah, which is lang-thing. The plan was to rename the current tag (after getting rid of Rust questions) to c++-chrono in line with that convention.

Comment: @Laurel How can I search for questions which are tagged [chrono] but neither [c++] nor [rust]?

Comment: `[chrono] -[rust] -[c++]`

Comment: Use `-[tag-name]` for each tag to exclude. Try [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono%20-rust%20-c%2b%2b). I've been adding the main language tag to questions that didn't have one.

Comment: I've checked all questions tagged [chrono] with neither of [rust], [c++] nor any c++ version. I removed the tag from some (one about some company's named DrChrono API and two about Android's Chronometer) and all the rest are about C++'s chrono, except three: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67522646/) is about a js library named react-chrono, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135765/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014809/) are about C++ Boost's chrono. What am I supposed to do with them?

Comment: Boost has a full suite of sub-libraries, there are some narrower tags for some of Boost's libraries (search for `[boost-*]` to see some of the tags) like `[boost-chrono]`. I'd use that tag since it already exists, but if it didn't, those questions could probably stand just fine with just `[boost]` (and a `C++` tag probably) alone.

Comment: @kmdreko: Questions about `std::chrono` should not be tagged `[boost-chrono]` (which currently has 2 questions, BTW).  C++ standard library features often start of as part of Boost and get standardized, but once they are standardized, that history isn't relevant, and it makes no sense to expect people to remember which things came fro boost and which didn't. In this case, `boost::chrono` was written to implement the C++11 chrono proposal before it became official, as a testing ground. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/chrono.html#chrono.overview.motivation

Comment: @PeterCordes I wasn't suggesting tagging `std::chrono` questions with `[boost-chrono]`, I was only responding to "what to do about C++ Boost's chrono" questions, to which I suggested that tag. And even if boost is the proving ground, its good to keep them separate and focused on which one the question-er is using since there may yet be differences between them.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the comment above yours mentioned Boost, and you were replying to that.  Nevermind.  Agreed that `[boost]` in general or `[boost-xyz]` in specific is appropriate for questions about the boost version of library code.

Comment: @Larnu There is no `chrono` in Rust. It's a [3rd-party library](https://crates.io/crates/chrono), unlike C++ where `std::chrono` is a core language library. Both are trying to solve similar problems in providing robust and universally usable date/time primitives, with only C++' `std::chrono` delivering on those goals.

Comment: I created [drchrono-api] and [react-chrono]. All the questions now that aren't tagged with [rust] or [c++] are about C++ or using its library in another language.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: It seems that all of the Rust stuff is out of the [tag:chrono] tag. So if it's going to be renamed, now's the time.

Comment: @NicolBolas Done. Thanks for the ping!

Answer (score 8):

If the intent is to split these tags, the current convention in C++ tags is that the "c++" part comes first. As seen in [c++-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-modules) or [c++-concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-concepts). So the tag ought to be [c++-chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-chrono)

Answer (score 7):

We already have [rust-chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-chrono). The stats at the time of writing are:

- 864 questions with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono)
- 46 questions with [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) and [rust-chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-chrono)
- 18 questions with both [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) and [chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono)

The outliers are the ones in the third bullet point. Any of us with edit privileges is in good position to edit these questions to use [rust-chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-chrono). Subsequently, [chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono) can be renamed to [c++-chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-chrono) and the former made a synonym of the latter, to prevent ambiguities and reduce the chance of misuse in the future.

This is no different from what was done with [the tags for `itertools`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421583/rename-itertools).

Comment: [Looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono+rust) all of the rust+chrono questions got cleaned up. Rename away!

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to split up the tag into two (or more) variants. Tag prefixes are pointless and annoying.

Because we allow questions to have multiple tags, questions about C++'s `std::chrono` functionality should be tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono). If you are interested in Rust questions about the Chrono library, then you search for "[rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) [chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrono) −[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)". There is no actual problem here to be solved.

Note that we don't have [c++-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-string), either; just [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) (and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)).

Comment: _"Note that we don't have c++-string, either"_ Mostly because string is a technology agnostic concept that may apply to a multitude of programming languages. Granted, we don't want one tag for each language with a string implementation. Giving an independent tag to a popular library is reasonable, OTOH. This suggestion also contradicts the prior tag handling policy that [tags should not refer to multiple things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421590). Tags in the past which have been split include [tag:itertools] and [tag:serde].

Comment: *"There is no actual problem here to be solved."* - That was my initial instinct as well. The [tag:chrono] tag is (or should be) orthogonal to the language it is being used with. If we start encoding language hints into tags that describe core principles, we're in for a combinatorial explosion that is detrimental to usability/discoverability. The only thing that should be done here is updating the [tag:chrono] usage guidance to deliver the message that `chrono` is commonly used to describe a concept, not a concrete implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable: "*chrono is commonly used to describe a concept, not a concrete implementation*" But it isn't. Until C++11 added the `<chrono>` header, if you had asked anybody what "chrono" meant, the most they could do was assume that it had something to do with time, because that's what the word literally means. It was never used to describe a concept; it was only ever used to describe the C++11 library component. And Rush uses that name for its similar component because... it borrowed the API and concepts from the C++ library.

Comment: @CodyGray: "*Note that we don't have c++-string, either; just string (and c++).*" But we do: [tag:stdstring]. And note that C++ actually has several string types: `char*`s, `std::string`, and `std::string_view`. So there is a distinction between questions asking about "string" and questions asking about `std::string`.

Comment: @NicolBolas `std::chrono` had been in the making since 2008. That's 14 years ago. For 70% of developers it had [always](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#experience-years-code) been there, and things that were true in 2011 are not necessarily true today. As for [tag:stdstring], I wonder why there is no `stdwstring`, `stdu8string`, `stdu16string`, and `stdu32string`. Multiply that by two if you think that `std::string_view` were a string. It doesn't appear to be immediately helpful to establish that sort of fragmentation.

Comment: @IInspectable: "*As for stdstring, I wonder why there is no stdwstring, stdu8string, stdu16string, and stdu32string.*" Because they are functionally the same type. People didn't make a tag for them because they have virtually identical interfaces. "*It doesn't appear to be immediately helpful to establish that sort of fragmentation.*" Yet it already exists. The chrono tag was specifically created for the C++ standard library component, not for general timing stuff. Allowing tag drift where it now means something other than what it was intended to mean makes no sense.

Comment: @IInspectable: "*For 70% of developers it had always been there, and things that were true in 2011 are not necessarily true today.*" That says absolutely nothing about whether the term "chrono" is understood as a generic term for "date/time library" (which is what you claimed it was). That just shows that most C++ programmers know that, when you say "chrono", you're asking about the **C++** date/time library. Not Rust's library, not Java's date/time library, not C#'s date/time library. Specifically C++'s library.

Comment: @NicolBolas *"Allowing tag drift where it now means something other than what it was intended to mean makes no sense."* - Maybe so, but what damage is done by allowing [tag:chrono] to be used in combination with, say, [tag:rust]? Does this make finding answers for C++ any harder? Does it cause any confusion for C++ developers? Rust developers? Developers using a language other than those two?

Comment: @IInspectable: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10273542/1) is what the Tag wiki looked like when people started dumping Rust questions into the chrono tag. If you allowed this, you would have to change the Tag wiki to say something very different. So... what would it be changed to? "The 'chrono' tag is for generic timing libraries?" That's redundant; we already have [tag:date],[tag:time], *and* [tag:datetime] for that.